# Centering <tr> in a email template

Tags: html, css, center

So I'm new to email html template design. I'm trying to align a `<tr>` in the center of a table. My supervisor is telling me not to use `align="center"`, but to use **CSS**. I was wondering if this was true.

Are you not suppose to use `align="center"` when designing email templates? If not what should I be using?

Comment: tr {text-align:center;}

Comment: use <td align="center"> don't center the tr.. Though it's probably easier if you post your HTML.

Comment: if you don't want to use `align="center"`, use `style="text-align:center;"`. overall, you should use inline-CSS.

Comment: or if all else fails, `<center>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<table border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Left Aligned</td>
        <td align="right">Right Aligned</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">Center Aligned</td>
        <td align="left">Left Aligned</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when using css for mail templates as some email clients do not recognise css (gmail bounces some css for example).

Try using a product such as mailchimp or email on acid which has previewers for how the completed mail shot will look on a variety of email softwares.

These are both web based services so you can sign up for trial versions.

Comment: Yup were using mail chimp. Also, within the <tr> are images and that is what im actually trying to center.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the img tag with a p tag and align center

Answer (score -1):

for emails, do not use `<style>` or included CSS file. best way to put style directly on elements. try to send email to different email clients and you will see difference.